# How to create JPA Specification join between entities

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I would like to create filter based on JPA Specification. I'm using spring-data.

My entites:

```java
public class Section {

    /*some other fields*/

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "section_objective",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "section_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "objective_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private List<Objective> objectives;

}
```

```java
public class Objective {

    /*some other fields*/

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "objective_question",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "objective_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```java
public class Question {

    /*some fields, below code is not important*/

}
```

Entity dependencies are: **Section** - one to many -> **Objective** - one to many -> **Question**
Entities do not have information about parent relationship (ex. I cannot go from Question to Objective the question is assigned to in Java code).

I have a Question filter class that converts to Specification. I would like to get all questions in section.

Normally I would use SQL query I've written below to get all questions in Section.

```sql
SELECT q.*
FROM
  question q
JOIN
  objective_question oq ON oq.question_id = q.id
JOIN
  objective o ON o.id = oq.objective_id
JOIN
  section_objective so ON so.objective_id = o.id
JOIN
  section s ON s.id = so.section_id
WHERE
  s.id IN (1,2);
```

I've tried creating specification with Join, but don't know how to create join when the reference to Objective on Question is not available.

```java
Specification.<Question>where((root, query, criteriaBuilder) ->
        root.join("section") /*throws error because **section** is not a part of attribute on Question */
                .in(List.of(1L, 2L)));
```

Comment: The format of your DB query looks more like a many-to-many query than a one-to-many query.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following library: https://github.com/turkraft/spring-filter

It will let you run search queries such as:

> */search?filter=* **average**(ratings) **>** 4.5 **and** brand.name **in** ('audi', 'land rover') **and** (year **>** 2018 **or** km **<** 50000) and color **:** 'white' **and** accidents **is empty**

You can also run search queries even if you don't have an API, the library basically compiles a search input to JPA predicates or to Specification if you desire so. It will smoothly handle all your join queries without having to worry about the well known n+1 query problem.

You may build specifications as follows:

```java
import static com.turkraft.springfilter.FilterBuilder.*;
Specification<Section> spec = new FilterSpecification<Section>(
  and(
    in("id", numbers(1, 2, 3)),
    equal("objectives.questions.field", "some value")
  )
);
// basically telling: get the sections which have id 1, 2 or 3, AND which have the field 'field' of the objectives questions' equal to 'some value'
```

You don't need to configure anything, just import the dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.turkraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-filter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```